# Searching for a replacement part for an SSD repair

Tags: identification, components, component-selection, ssd

I broke my SSD after applying 28 V and I have to change the component by the red arrows in the picture. The component is marked  "FNC1B" and it is QFN10 package. It should be a MOSFET or an optocoupler. Below the component "P LN" is a PTC. The FNC1B and PTC  drive the same line (5 V line.)  On some SSDs (same model) the FNC1B is placed while on others the PTC is placed.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you actually broke the PTC? Because that would be a very hard thing to do.

Comment: PTC is not mounted. This image has same configuration with my ssd board. PTC is mounted in this board above picture, FNC1B is mounted in my ssd board. PTC is dismounted in my SSD board. In my opinion FNC1B was broken in my board, because when I dismounted FNC1B from my board short circuit is vanished.

Comment: _"It should be MOSFET or optocoupler."_ What led you to this conclusion?

Comment: 28 V is quite a lot for a low voltage logic device. Are you really sure nothing else got fried (like the controller or the flash itself)? Given that this looks like an entirely ordinary cheap SATA SSD, I suspect that repairing it is going to be much more expensive than just replacing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package and markings match with a [Silergy SY6875A](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2207121830_Silergy-Corp-SY6875ADBC_C3030895.pdf) current limit switch.

[image]

You can find images on [LCSC](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Surge-Suppressors_Silergy-Corp-SY6875ADBC_C3030895.html) to confirm the markings style also matches.

Comment: Thank you so much. How did you find this although only from a picture and some letters on it?

Comment: @123456 Since it was an alternative to a PTC, I searched LCSCs "TVS/Fuse/Board Level Protection" category and filtered by the package in question. LCSC has pictures for all parts they stock, so you can look for matching markings quickly without opening datasheets.